# Limit object view bounds, or better blur technique in Sketch

Tags: blur, sketch-app

### Using Sketch, I'm trying to duplicate the **blur** approach used in this image [(source)](https://dribbble.com/shots/2061540-Wibee-web-client-profile/attachments/368725):

[image]

---

But I can't figure out how to blur properly in Sketch. The closest approach I could find was using **background blur**.

Instead of a **constant blur**, I end up with blurred white sides [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkOvR.png), when my result should look like [this accidental result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k32nT.png) that I **cannot** replicate.

Right now the 2 fixes I see for this are:

- Find a better way to blur in Sketch
- Figure out a way to limit the view bounds of a single object, similar to crop, but it's more of a "view boundary mask"

I am definitely open to other approaches.

Comment: Perhaps things changed in the latest versions, but I can't reproduce your problem: when I use background blur I get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to solve this problem:

1. Place layer above your image. Add gradient fill with same color at ends (#000000) set 0% alpha on one endpoint and 100% alfa on another. Make point of gradient be at same place as on picture below. Make this layer as Alpha Mask () <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

[image: gradient fill]

2. Add empty layer bigger than layer mask, this will remove white borders. Apply background blur 6px on this layer. This layer is the masked one by the alpha blur layer.

[image: alpha mask]

[Download](http://ge.tt/5hknAnM2/v/0?c) sample Sketch file.

Good [article](https://medium.com/@zsedbal/cool-background-blur-effect-to-your-ios-or-android-application-made-in-sketch-dfe48f093fc9) on this technique.